# Is there a better way to write this addition function?

Tags: python, sum, addition

Can the following method be written any shorter (without semicolons) in Python in a way I have not seen?

```
@staticmethod
def __add(a, b):
    value = a + b
    if value > 1:
        integer = int(value)
        if value == integer:
            return 1.0
        return value - integer
    if value < 0:
        integer = int(value)
        if value == integer:
            return 0.0
        return value - integer + 1
    return value
```

The code is like `%` except that it allows the endpoint of whatever the code is modding the end value to.

Comment: Put `integer = int(value)` before the `if` statements. You have the same line twice when you should only have it once. (Also you could store some of those tests in variables but I don't think that's really necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return 1 - (-value%1) if value > 0 else value%1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
value = (a + b) % 1.0
if (value == 0.0 and a + b > 0) value = 1.0
```

I'm not sure why the `a + b > 0` condition is necessary on the second line, but it matches the behavior in your code of returning 1 if `a + b` is a positive integer and 0 if `a + b` is zero or a negative integer.  What is the specific reason you want to return 1 when `a + b` is an integer rather than 0?

EDIT: Looking at the documentation further, that first line should probably be `value = fmod(a + b, 1.0) + (1.0 if a + b < 0.0 else 0.0)` (`fmod` recommended for more precision, with that second part to correct the sign of the result).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method. Color values outside the range of `0.0 - 1.0` are correctly modded.

```
@staticmethod
def __mod(value):
    div, mod = divmod(value, 1)
    if div > 0 and not mod:
        return 1.0
    return mod
```